# Issue loading config file array within MVC/OOP structured PHP

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

I am creating a basic MVC structured CMS in PHP as a means to learn how MVC works (thus the reason I am not using a true prebuilt engine). I have a basic version working and am currently trying to shift information over to a config file like so:

**config.php**

```
 <?php
    return array(
        //  MySQL database details
        'database' => array(
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'port' => '',
            'username' => '',
            'password' => '',
            'name' => '',
            'collation' => 'utf8_bin'
        ),

        // Application settings
        'application' => array(
            // url paths
            'default_controller' => 'index',
            'default_action' => 'index',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
        ),

        // Session details
        'session' => array(
            'name' => '',
            'expire' => 3600,
            'path' => '/',
            'domain' => ''
        ),

        // Error handling
        'error' => array(
            'ignore' => array(E_NOTICE, E_USER_NOTICE, E_DEPRECATED, E_USER_DEPRECATED),
            'detail' => false,
            'log' => false
        )
    );
```

I am including it in the index.php file like this:

**index.php**

```
define ('__SITE_PATH', $site_path);
$config = include __SITE_PATH . '/config.php';
```

However, when I try to load it later in a template file for testing, or any other file for that matter nothing is returned. Is this an issue with classes? If anyone could shed some light on the matter I'd be very appreciative.

Here is the full index.php for more reference:

```
<?php

    /*** error reporting on ***/
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    /*** define the site path ***/
    $site_path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
    define ('__SITE_PATH', $site_path);

    $config = include __SITE_PATH . '/config.php';

    /*** include the controller class ***/
    include __SITE_PATH . '/application/' . 'controller_base.class.php';

    /*** include the registry class ***/
    include __SITE_PATH . '/application/' . 'registry.class.php';

    /*** include the router class ***/
    include __SITE_PATH . '/application/' . 'router.class.php';

    /*** include the template class ***/
    include __SITE_PATH . '/application/' . 'template.class.php';

    /*** auto load model classes ***/
    function __autoload($class_name) {
        $filename = strtolower($class_name) . '.class.php';
        $file = __SITE_PATH . '/model/' . $filename;
        if (file_exists($file) == false) {
            return false;
        }
        include ($file);
    }

    /*** a new registry object ***/
    $registry = new registry;

    /*** load the router ***/
    $registry->router = new router($registry);

    /*** set the controller path ***/
    $registry->router->setPath (__SITE_PATH . '/controller');

    /*** load up the template ***/
    $registry->template = new template($registry);

    /*** load the controller ***/
    $registry->router->loader();
```

Comment: The code looks right to me. Did you try to print the paths to make sure you are including the correct files?

Comment: Yep. Did that twice now.

Comment: If you `include full/path/to/config.php` then `var_dump($config);` you get nothing? I just did a simple test on my machine and it works for me.

Comment: It will load in some files, such as the file it was called, then the say "router.class.php". However when I try to do a var_dump in a file called by the router / template class it won't load at all as though there is no $config at all

Comment: You should only have **one** `include` statement, and that would be to include an autoloader, like one generated by [composer](https://getcomposer.org/). Also, we don't do "class.php" any more, you need to look at PSR-0 / PSR-4 and how the name of the class should be the name of the file so it can be autoloaded and you don't need to type "include" to get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are doing this all wrong.

Instead of creating complicated configuration I find it much easier to initialize all the structures at bootstrap stage, and then [inject the dependencies](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0) where required.

For example, instead to have connection configuration for database, you create a closure, which then can be injected in a factory of [data mappers](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html).

```
$dbhProvider = function()
{
    $instance = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=foobar;charset=UTF-8', 
                         'user', 
                         'password');
    $instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    return $instance;
};
```

And similar principles can be applied for dealing with session management and routing mechanism.

And **what the hell is this** ?

> 'ignore' => array(E_NOTICE, E_USER_NOTICE, E_DEPRECATED, E_USER_DEPRECATED),

Why would you ignore warnings related to your code quality? That is just stupid.